# CSS selector for elements having focus outline in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, focus

If you navigate page by TAB in Chrome it indicates focus on elements by adding an outline. The problem is that the outline is drawn outside, so I need to apply *z-index* to such outlined elements, so that the outline does not get hidden by elements with higher *z-index* than that of the focused element.

I've tried the `:focus` selector, but it seems that an element can be focused in Chrome yet have no outline (e.g. if you click it with mouse). What is then the valid selector to apply a style to all outlined and only the outlined elements?

EDIT: What I mean by a focus without an outline is like in the following example:

```
<style> a:focus{color:red} </style>
<a href="#">abc</a><br>
<a href="#">def</a>
```

When you TAB over such links, they got both styled by the :focus rule and outlined, yet when you click them with mouse the style is applied but the element is not outlined by the browser.

Comment: What do you mean focused without outline? If i create a simple text input and select it with the mouse it is also focused? `:focus` should be the correct tag

Comment: data:text/html,<style>a:focus{color:red}</style><a href="#">abc</a><br><a href="#">def</a>

When you tab such links they both get outlined and have focus styling. When you click them, they have no outline but do have the focus styling.

Comment: Right! Good point! `a` elements are not getting an outline on click. With TAB they do. Some day i read about a `:focus-ring` selector but i think W3C didn't do aynthing on that.

Answer (score 2):

For Firefox you can read up on the [:-moz-focusring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:-moz-focusring) selector.

Answer (score 0):

Add custom css for outline style.

```css
a{border:1px solid #fff;}
a:focus{color:red;
outline:none; 
border:1px solid #4D90FE;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px  #4D90FE;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px  #4D90FE;}
```

```html
<a href="#">abc</a><br>
<a href="#">def</a>
```

Comment: This is no answer to his question. He want's a selector for all currently outlined elements.